# Button Update in gridview and get value from hidden textbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

The button in the gridview can't get the correct value from the hidden textbox.

Here is the code:

asp:

```
<columns>
  <asp:TemplateField >
      <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtFruit" runat="server" Visible="true" Text='<%# Bind("txtFruit")%>'  />
      </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>

     <asp:BoundField DataField="HiddentxtFruit" HeaderText ="Fruit" HeaderStyle-Width="0%" HtmlEncode="false" Visible="false"   />

     </asp:TemplateField>


            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Confirm">
 <ItemTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Confirm" runat="server"  CommandName="Submit" />

 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>

</columns>
```

code behind:

```
 For intX As Integer = 0 To gridview1.Rows.Count - 1
   Dim txtPLACE As TextBox = TryCast(gridview1.Rows(0).Cells(0).FindControl("txtFruit"), TextBox)
Next
```

or

```
 For intX As Integer = 0 To gridview1.Rows.Count - 1
   Dim txtPLACEss As TextBox = DirectCast(gridview1.Rows(intX).FindControl("txtFruit"), TextBox)
Next
```

This will only get the first row from the gridview.

Comment: are you using Row_updating event?

Comment: @RamSingh no, i use button click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below code to get index of the row:

```
Dim rowIndex = DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, Control).NamingContainer, GridViewRow).RowIndex
```

And then

```
 Dim txtPLACEss As TextBox = DirectCast(gridview1.Rows(rowIndex).FindControl("txtFruit"), TextBox)
```

That will solve your problem

**UPDATE :**

```
 <asp:TemplateField >
  <ItemTemplate><asp:TextBox ID="txtFruit" runat="server" Visible="true" Text='<%# Bind("txtFruit")%>'  /></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFruitHidden" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("txtFruit")%>'  HeaderStyle-Width="0%" HtmlEncode="false" Visible="false" />

 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Then in C#

```
     Dim txtPLACEss As TextBox = DirectCast(gridview1.Rows(rowIndex).FindControl("txtFruitHidden"), TextBox)
```

Hope this will resolve your problem ..

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.forms_fruit_stock_fruits_aspx' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow
it can't cast using the way you provide

Comment: I just provided the way to get the index of that row from which button is being click that's what you asked i think.. :)

Comment: txtFruit is boundField not textbox, that's why you are facing this problem... just use the updated code:

Comment: sorry i my mistake putting the two name as once, is already update still have the same problem

Comment: @AndrewMadMan. bro.. i had convert that bound field to Textbox.. just change it to textbox and then try as i have written code in my answer..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144221/discussion-between-ram-singh-and-andrew-madman).